# Am trying to sort datatable dt, but its not working. Time Elapsed is my column name in dt. want to sort by DESC

Tags: asp.net

```
public static DataTable resort(DataTable dt)       
{

    string sortByColumnsStr = "Time Elapsed  DESC";
    DataView dtview = new DataView(dt);
    dtview.Sort = sortByColumnsStr;
    DataTable dtsorted = dtview.ToTable();        
    return dtsorted;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Embed the column name with square brackets, like this:

```
string sortByColumnsStr = "[Time Elapsed] DESC";
```

You can eventually take a look at this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/1f37f760-b479-4b4a-a2db-0e828812ac0e/